# elasticsearch in aws how to temporarily shutdown cluster to update from dev console

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to shutdown an elastic cluster by cluster_id using the dev console?  Our elastic search is running in the cloud, so the solutions I have seen online don't work, and I am looking for a Kibana dev console solution.  It seems that there is no setting for this in elastic.co deployment management either.

we need this to update a dynamic parameter ("cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.enable_for_single_data_node).  when I try to do it on our live cluster I get the error:

"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "persistent setting [cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.enable_for_single_data_node], not dynamically updateable"
},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic formal support team has confirmed that for the cloud setup, it is impossible to do this without downtime.  Updating this type of setting requires updating the yml file.  Quote from support team:

"Static settings can only be configured on an unstarted or shut down node using elasticsearch.yml."

The restart and downtime for a cloud setup mut be done by the support team.